# How do I customize the background of a Select or SelectItem?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, next.js

The background of each select item is black, the background of the Select is also black.
Everything can be customized, except the area around each Select Item, which I believe is the area around {games.map}. It is white and I cannot seem to change that color.

[image]

```
        <>
          <Select
            label="Select a game"
            value={selectedGame?.id.toString() || ""}
            onChange={handleGameChange}
            className=" max-w-xs bg-background text-foreground dark"
          >
            {games.map((game) => (
              <SelectItem
                className=" max-w-xs bg-background text-foreground dark"
                key={game.id}
                value={game.id.toString()}
              >
                {game.name}
              </SelectItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </>
```

[image]

It looks to be one of the parent divs and an ul in the inspector.